# Why are my orange trees dropping new leaves and getting dry?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, leaves, citrus

Up until a few days ago, these orange trees were doing fine and well. They had nice new growth. Since three days ago I've been finding them dropping some of the newer leaves, along with some of the twigs going dark and dry.

Is this normal? I just bought them last year so I'm not yet familiar with how they behave during spring time.

[image][image][image: [enter image description here][image][image][image]

Comment: The plant in the second picture looks very close to the wall. Has the end of the branch just been rubbed against the wall by the wind, or by a bird landing on it and bending it, or something like that?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. It's actually not that close to the wall as the photo makes it out to be. Besides the tree next to it is also loosing twigs and not just on the side facing the wall but all sides and most noticeably at the top where you'll see leafless twigs and btw these are all last year twigs not new. First the old leaves went yellow and fell from the twigs and now the same twigs are going yellow before going dead. If you notice, leaves that appear bigger in size in the photo are all from last year.

Comment: Can we get close-ups of the twigs? You may have a fungal attack going on. It will be easier to diagnose if we can see the coloration, extent of damage, spots etc. closer. Citrus Fruit diseases are well documented. Alternately, they may be due for fertilization.

Comment: @srihari yamanoor_ sure thing. I'll add them to the rest of the photos I've already uploaded.